# join tables in sql where data does not exactly match up

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I have two tables that I want to join. I have provided something below that shows how my data looks. I want to join the two tables on the given columns, but how can I do this with the "ID" in front of the number in table B? I was thinking of a trim on the join, but I don't know how to do that.

Something like...

```
Select *                    
From TableA AS A          
Left Join TableB AS B        
On A.ColumnA = B.ColumnB
```

But this won't work because the numbers don't completely match up.

```
TableA ColumnA   
123        
456        
789        

TableB ColumnB              
ID123                  
ID456                    
ID789
```

I hope I made this clear enough. Any suggestions?

Comment: `on ('ID' + A.ColumnA) = B.ColumnB` assuming whatever database you're using can properly convert the datatypes and you want to keep the 'ID'.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh seems to have a good suggestion. Depending on your database, you might need to concatenate strings with  "||" rather than "+". Also, if those digits are actually a numeric type, you'd probably need to convert to a string type first. Another option would involve adding a view with a computed column suitable for joining the two tables.

Comment: For all databases, such code should never appear in production. Applying functions on fields prevents the database from using any indexes,  resulting in full table scans. *WHY* do you try to join the tables in this way?  A better option is to split ColumnB, perhaps using a calculated column, and create an index on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0bb56/1)**

```
select *
from tableA a
join tableB b 
  on 'ID' + cast(columnA as varchar(5)) = b.columnB
```

Comment: This will result in a full table scan, as the query optimizer can't use any defined indexes. It may produce correct results but it can't be used in production. Additionally, the cast isn't necessary as the server will cast any numeric columns to a string anyway

Comment: Numeric and int both throw an error for me in SQL Server 2014 if not explicitly converted so I put it in to be safe.

Comment: I get error message: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ID117882' to data type int.

Comment: Do you have your tables mixed up or reversed? What does your query look like?